# Disable Flutter's dependency overrides warning

Tags: flutter, dart, config, warnings, pubspec

I am using melos which depends on dependency overrides and I always get these annoying warnings:

**"Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:"**

I have looked into the documentation of flutter warnings but I did not find any appropriate warning key to disable it.

Does anybody know if there is a possibility to disable this warning?

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
linter:
  rules:
    depend_on_referenced_packages: false
```

in `analysis_options.yaml` file

Comment: This does not surpress the warnings